# How to use bash variable with double and single quotes

Tags: json, linux, bash, shell, parsing

i am writing personal parser for json on bash. So, i need to make grep of line. For example, part of my json-file.

```
{
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "hhost": "127.0.0.2",
}
```

Of course, after trying `cat json.txt | grep host`, i received:

```
"host": "127.0.0.1",
"hhost": "127.0.0.1",
```

I found, how to find only `host` without `hhost`. I used

`cat json.txt | grep '"host"'`

Everything is good

`"host": "127.0.0.1",`

But i want to use it in bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#in a future, i want to read variable var from reading from console 
var=host
search='"$var"'
echo $search
```

In a result, i have:

```
"$var"
```

What i did wrong ? Can you advice me please ?

Comment: `search=$var` and then `echo "$search"` is probably closer to what you want, but it's not 100% clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you put a variable inside single quotes in bash, I does not get evaluated, you should just use:

```
search="$var"
```

if you want the variable to be enclosed by quotes, just escape them like this:

```
search="\"$var\""
```

Comment: The quotes aren't necessary in the first example, but maybe the second example is more like what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), to parse the JSON file for this you will need first a proper valid json

```
{
  "host": "127.0.0.1",
  "hhost": "127.0.0.2"
}
```

Then you could just do something like:

```
#/bin/sh

HOST=$(jq '.host' data.json)
echo $HOST
...
```